# How to control addView to a layout

Tags: android, view, padding

I add a graphview programatically :

```
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams Lparams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, p.y/2);
```

//same result with fill_parent or match_parent

```
    Lparams.gravity = Gravity.LEFT;

    firstGraph.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);

    firstGraph.setLayoutParams(Lparams);

    LinearLayout RelLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.relLayout);

    RelLayout.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    RelLayout.addView(firstGraph, 0);
```

I obtain this:
[image: Problem]

What i want is to eliminate that left gap of the graphview, I don't know why is there, I only set a padding of 10 that is what you have in right side.

Any Suggestions? Thansk in advance.

the layout xml:

```
            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/relLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the space doesn't come from the graph view?

Comment: I'm not sure, but i don't think graph view has space.

Comment: Well can you post some details of the graph view? It is made by you(maybe you can share some code) or is from a library?

Comment: It's not mine, it from this blog: http://www.jjoe64.com/p/graphview-library.html

Comment: I think that space is the space needed for the axis labels. You could copy the code and try to modify the values in the `GraphViewConfig` class and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks @Luksprog I won't change it because i want to put something there, but thanks!, If you want write this as answer and I mark it as the good answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That space most likely appears because it is the space reserved for the axis labels(and as you probably don't set any labels it's an empty space). If you do need to remove it you'll have to modify the graph view's code and change the values in `GraphViewConfig`(as those seem to be the values used).

Answer (score 0):

setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) is the sytax of setPadding. The first argument is for the left padding. You are giving 10. Try setPadding(0, 0, 10, 0)

Comment: Same thing occurs, just a little bit to the left, but still a "big" gap.